# argmentparser object has no attribute 'parser_args'

Tags: python

Why am I getting argumentParser object has no attribute 'parser_args'. Here is my syntax

```
   import argparse

   def fib(n):
      a, b = 0, 1
      for i in range(n):
         a, b = b, a+b
     return a

  def Main():
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument("num", help="The fibonacci numember",type=int)
      args = parser.parser_args()

      result = fib(args.num)
      print ("The ", str(args.num), "the number is ", str(result) )

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      Main()
```

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnatu3xxVQE) is where I found the syntax while learning how to work with argument parser. Can you help me identify whats wrong with syntax? Unlike the link, I am using python 3

Comment: You need to `parse_args()`.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You have a typing error in your code. The code should be

```
parser.parse_args()
```